# MKAnnontation pin image resize issue

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Custom pin image for `MKAnnotation`. When tapping or zooming map the custom pin gets stretched and opening for home map car pin marker are big in size. Here is output result which I'm getting in mapview:

[image]

Here is the code which I have tried so far:

```
var pin = MKAnnotationView()
var userPinView: MKAnnotationView!

if annotation is MKUserLocation {

    pin = mapView.view(for: annotation) ?? MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    let pinImage = UIImage(named: "carIcon3")
    let size = CGSize(width: 38, height: 44)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    pinImage!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    pin.image = resizedImag
    userPinView = pin
    userPinView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    userPinView.clipsToBounds = true
    return pin
}

if !(annotation is MKPointAnnotation) {
    return nil
}

let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"
var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)

if annotationView == nil {
    annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
    //            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
} else {
    annotationView!.annotation = annotation
}
return annotationView
```

How to get result like this:

[image]

Tried to user current location marker. But it crashing

```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.005) {

        let angle = newHeading.trueHeading.toRadians() // convert from degrees to radians

        self.userPinView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle)) // rotate the picture
    }
}
```

here the code which i have performing didselect and deselect for location annotation.

```
     func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    if annotView == true {

        let heights = 70

        let widths = 50

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

            view.frame.size = CGSize(width: widths, height: heights)

        })
    }

}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    let heights = 70

    let widths = 50

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

        view.frame.size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width - CGFloat(widths), height: view.frame.height - CGFloat(heights))

    })
}
```

Comment: tried without UIGraphicsEndImageContext , nothing come out

Comment: I'm new to this, do you recommend any sample..

Comment: Personally, I’d (a) get this car resizing/drawing logic out of there and just have appropriately sized images; (b) I’d register classes for the two types of annotations; (c) I’d move configuration of the annotation views into those subclasses adjust have them set their respective `image` property. E.g. something like: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/a33a94eb429b5a138553af409220f7eb. The MKMapViewDelegate should probably get out of the business of configuring annotation views, and the annotation view should configure itself.

Comment: The problem is, though, that I cannot reproduce your problem, so I fear that the problem (if not the missing up `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` call) is something unrelated to what you have here. I’d suggest you focus on creating a [simpler, reproducible example of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with my image, please provide the original image so I will be testing it further

Comment: ok sure!!!!!!..

Comment: @AamirR can you icon from this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JkA8TZ-sR6h1x2-MN4YMxfWDVHKKJ8ja/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I did download, check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I cannot reproduce the issue, but recommend couple of changes:

1. separate the view configuration logic, lets subclass `MKAnnotationView`, like so:

   ```
   class CarAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
       override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
           didSet {
               let size = CGSize(width: 38, height: 44)
               UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
               UIImage(named: "carIcon")?.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
               self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
               UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. change within `mapView(_:viewFor:)` to take advantage of the reusable view, like so:

   ```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
       if annotation is MKUserLocation {
           userPinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "carId") as? CarAnnotationView
           if (userPinView == nil) {
               userPinView = CarAnnotationView(annotation: nil, reuseIdentifier: "carId")
           }

           userPinView.annotation = annotation
           userPinView.setNeedsLayout()
           // userPinView.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -view.bounds.midY)

           return userPinView
       }

       guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }

       let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"
       ...
       return annotationView

   }
   ```
3. delete unnecessary variable

   ```
   var pin = MKAnnotationView()
   ```

Comment: I have two issue 1.) user car icon not rotating 2.) i have user location annotation as car icon and having multiple other location marker, when didselect on location marker the user location car icon marker disappears..

Comment: i have updated my questions too. can you help me out of this

Comment: please post separate question(s) and send me the link here, will be glad to help!

Comment: It also solved my problem about the Pins dissapearing when long pressing on them or when I close and reopen the App